# How to bend a mesh along a circle in three.js?

Tags: javascript, graphics, three.js

I want to bend or curve a text mesh along a circle. I'm working on it from 4 days but still can't get any solution.

I use Bend-modifier library to bed the text. It helps but it bends the object from center only. So if i want to make a circle it cant help me. i.e. If I bend the text 90 degree's it'll be a 'U' shape text.

I just want to make it complete circle or even a half circle. It bends in a way that no shape will lost. It's width remain same.

```
    textMesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, materials);

    var bendModifier = new THREE.BendModifier();
    var direction = new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, -1);
    var axis = new THREE.Vector3(0, 1, 0);
    var angle = Math.PI/2.6
    bendModifier.set(direction, axis, angle).modify(textMesh.geometry);
    scene.add(textMesh);
```

But I want this to make a perfect half circle of text in the scene

Anyone knows how to do it?

Comment: A live code example of what you've tried would be great.

Comment: @prisoner849 I updated some code